After I added I added shouldBeStrict to model raised error Undefined array key
In laravel 11 / livewire 3 / app I added shouldBeStrict to model :
class Currency extends Model implements HasMedia
{
protected $table = 'currencies';
protected $primaryKey = 'id';
public $timestamps = false;

protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    if(App::isLocal()) {
        Model::shouldBeStrict();
    }
}

So now I can not use code like :
$currency->selected = true;

So I add 2 custom attributes in model :
protected $appends = ['select', 'mediaData'];

...


// Set select value.
public function setSelectAttribute(bool $value): void
{
    $this->attributes['select'] = $value;
}
// Get select value.
function getSelectAttribute()
{
    return $this->attributes['select'];   // ERROR POINTING TO THIS LINE
}


// Set mediaData value.
public function setMediaDataAttribute(array $value): void
{
    $this->attributes['mediaData'] = $value;
}
// Get mediaData value.
function getMediaDataAttribute(): array
{
    return $this->attributes['mediaData'];
}

But with first request to this model :
    foreach ($this->currencies as $currency) {
        var_dump($currency->select);
    }

I got error :
Undefined array key "select"

How to fix it ?

shouldBeStrict seems to prevent lazy loading, prevent accessing missing attributes and silently discarding attributes. I don't see any reason why $currency->selected = true; is not valid as long as selected is a fillable attribute?

No, selected is not a table field or a fillable attribute - I use to to make a selection list based on model.

sounds like a strange way to handle this, storing this dynamic state on the object itself. can you include an example of what/how you are using this selected value? if this is not a table col, you should not modify models attributes at any point, as those might be used to persist the model in your db

Say, list of currencies with 20 elements. User can select from 1 till 20 or not at all. If you considel adding selected field in model a bad way, how would you implement it ?

I don't know what you are doing so I can't tell for sure. Normally I would think to store the selected/preferred currency in session or cache if I want to persist it between requests. or do $selectedCurrencies = Currency::query()->findMany($request->input('currencies', [])) if I want those for one request. Again I don't see how you are using this $currency->selected after you have set it?

In db in related table are saved data with $currency->selected = true

ok now we are getting somewhere, so it a relation value. likely a user preference stored in a pivot user_currencies table. In this case "getting" this value from the currency model does not make much sense without the context of the related model, in this example: user

class Currency extends Model implements HasMedia
{
    protected $table = 'currencies';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $timestamps = false;
    // Define custom attributes that should be appended to the model's JSON form
    protected $appends = ['select', 'mediaData'];
    // Internal variables to hold custom attribute values
    protected $customAttributes = [
        'select' => false, // Default value for `select`
        'mediaData' => [], // Default value for `mediaData`
    ];
    // Override the boot method for strict mode if in local environment
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        if (App::isLocal()) {
            Model::shouldBeStrict();
        }
    }
    public function setSelectAttribute(bool $value): void
    {
        $this->customAttributes['select'] = $value;
    }
    public function getSelectAttribute()
    {
        return $this->customAttributes['select'] ?? false;
    }
    public function setMediaDataAttribute(array $value): void
    {
        $this->customAttributes['mediaData'] = $value;
    }

    // Get mediaData value (retrieve it from the custom attributes array)
    public function getMediaDataAttribute(): array
    {
        return $this->customAttributes['mediaData'] ?? [];
    }
}

Try this 


Is it from official docs(I do not see anything like that in docs https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/eloquent-mutators) or some kind of hack? Seems I used atributes before in prior versions before shouldBeStrict was added.

this resolved your issue or any error you found. Custom Attributes via Accessor/Mutator without storing them in $attributes: You can manage these attributes using internal variables or append them dynamically when needed.
We're using a private property $customAttributes to store the values for select and mediaData, since they're not part of the underlying database table.
You can retrieve and set these values using the getSelectAttribute and setSelectAttribute methods, and similarly for mediaData.
Setting Default Values:
